# How to use reflection to handle all types?

Tags: c#, reflection, types

I was trying to do many utility functions like this:

```
public bool HasMember(object obj, string name)
{
etc.
}
```

The name and meaning of this particular utility function are not relevant.

Unfortunately, the function above cannot handle all types, like DateTime or Decimal which are structs. It handles integers and custom objects well. I understand that c# have both structs and objects, and struct is not an object. But how can I handle all the types in my utility method? It is preferable that there are no overloaded methods because there are so many utility functions needed.

*Previous Research:*

The language reference did not give me advice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs

Also no help with the text explaining the value types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types

Comment: "cannot handle all types" - why not? There's nothing immediately obvious from the scant amount of code you've shown us that shouts to me "this will not work for `DateTime`". Can you post a *complete* code sample that demonstrates an issue?

Comment: ok, now i get it. struct inherits from class (!) called ValueType which inherits from object: [here is link to  MS site for reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: *"struct is not an object"* ***Everything*** in C# is an object!

Comment: ok i get it now, you are right. i was confused. It should be said "structs are not classes" but both are still objects... interestingly, struct inherit class called ValueType.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *can* handle all types. `object` works like a "wildcard". Just pass your `DateTime` in!

It does, however, cause boxing when you pass a value type (structs like `DateTime`). Boxing is basically wrapping a value type into a reference type. This may or may not cause problems.

If you don't want boxing, consider generics:

```
public bool HasMember<T>(T obj, string name)
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me thru of my confusion. Marked as an answer. I am not sure why the boxing acted like it did but the problem with my question was that i actually did not understand the problem itself very well, thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

In C# value of any type, no matter `class` or `struct`, could be assigned to `Object` variable. These are the valid constructs:

```
object obj = new DateTime();
object obj2 = 100m;
```

So if your utility method has signature as you specified

```
public bool HasMember(object obj, string name)
```

you could call it both on classes and structs, like `DateTime` and `Decimal`.

Comment: If I call it with Decimal? (Nullable  struct), the object is converted to decimal, why? That is why i thought that struct is not an object. Why it does the casting?

Comment: decimal and Decimal are synonyms. You probably should read about boxing/unboxing - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing

Comment: so you are saying that i should use Decimal, i though those are the same, i was wrong. thank you. so perhaps Decimal? (which is struct and object) does not cast to Decimal? i still dont get it why Nullable<decimal> does cast to to decimal for some reason? this happens in my unit test project which calls the utility function, the object is not anymore the same